# How to kill a single process in Python at any point of its execution?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm fairly new to Python and have created an rudimentary application that runs a series of what is functionally macros for the user to automate some tedious processes with an existing application. Some of these processes take a while, and others I would like to run infinitely until a user hits a key to stop it. It is a small program and I was in a hurry, so the easiest solution was throwing a stop field into my classes and putting "if stop -> return/break" in numerous spots throughout my methods. The code below should demonstrate the general idea.

```
class ExampleClass:
  stop = false

  def stop_doing_stuff(self):
    stop = true

  def do_stuff(self):
    if stop:
      return
    else:
      for i in range(10000):
        if stop:
          return
        else:
          do_thing()
```

This seems clearly to me as an amateur solution, and I would like to know how this could be done better. I'm sure there is a way to accomplish this with threading, but I've only briefly worked with threads in the past so was not sure how at the time. I was most curious though as to whether there is perhaps an even easier solution which does not involve launching a thread since I'm in no need of multiple processes running concurrently.

Edit:
I forgot to mention this is a GUI application running. The user is pressing buttons which will do the tasks for them. However, the GUI is hidden as a task is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You may catch a `KeyboardInterrupt`:

```
try:
    for i in range(10000):
        do_things()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    return
```

Comment: Will that be thrown if a user is not interacting with the console? I went back to edit my post to include the info that this is a GUI application and ideally the user would not have access to the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can immediately terminate a script with a specified exit status using `sys.exit(exit_status)`:

```py
import sys

def foo():
    sys.exit(0) # exit with success status (zero)
    sys.exit(1) # exit with error status (non-zero)
```

If you want to terminate the script via keyboard you need only Ctrl + C / Cmd + C it. You can handle that interrupt gracefully using `signal`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import signal
import sys

def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    print('You pressed Ctrl+C!')
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
print('Press Ctrl+C to terminate')

# ..perform work here..
```